# $L^p$ bounds for linear operators

Tags: harmonic-analysis

A typical way to show $L^{p}$ boundedness of a linear or sub-linear operator is to show a weak type $(1,1)$ bound and an $L^{p}$ bound for some $p$, and then combine these two using interpolation to prove $L^{p}$ bounds for all $p$ between $1$ and $\infty$. A typical example is that of the Hardy-Littlewood maximal Operator. Are there any examples\techniques where $L^{p}$ boundedness is proved without establishing some type of weak type bounds?

Answer (score 1):

One can work directly with $L^p$ (not using interpolation), and there is a good reason to do so when a sharp bound for the operator norm is desired. See, for example, [The Hunt for a Bellman function](http://www.math.brown.edu/~treil/papers/bellman/abstract/abstract.html) by Nazarov and Treil.